# Like Button with counters using html css & jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'd like to include a "like" button on a website with a counter. The like buttons include a tally for the current number of likes. If it is not clicked, the current number of likes is displayed. When a button is clicked, the current number of clicks is increased by one (and the button's state or appearance changes), and the like count should be stored on server-side logic to store and serve the number of likes.

Is it possible to achieve this in HTML, CSS, and Jquery?

Comment: Yes. This is possible. You should write some code and come back if you run into any problems. @Siddharth OP mentions he wants to use some backend tech.

Comment: That would require me to write both front- and back-end code, and that's not how SO works. If you don't know how to approach this you either to look at the documentation/tutorials for jQuery/AJAX and whatever backend tech you need and figure it out, or hire someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet :)

```js
      let likes = 0;
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // ajax to get current likes
        // let likes from server are 10
        // assign the current likes to variable
        likes = 10;
        setLikes(likes);
      });
      
      $("body").on("click", ".likeBtn", function () {
        // ajax to post a current likes
        // in success add increment to likes
        likes++;
        setLikes(likes);
      });

      function setLikes(count) {
        $(".totalLikes").text(count);
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Likes Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="likeBtn">
      Like (<span class="totalLikes">0</span>)
    </button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```